# Where are "don't ask again" settings stored in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When you paste java code into kotlin one Android Studio by default asks if you wan't the code be converted. I set "Don't ask again" checkbox and pressed Yes. Now when I try to paste java code it sometimes gives me "Cannot perform operation. Too complex, sorry" popup message and pastes no code at all!

Where are the "don't ask again" settings stored to disable that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one place for all *don't ask again* settings.

This particular one can be found in the settings, under **Editor > General > Smart Keys**.

Here's a screenshot from IntelliJ IDEA, which should match Android Studio for this setting:

[image: settings dialog]

Comment: I can confirm, the location of this setting in AndroidStudio is analog to IntelliJ IDEA.
Unticking the second checkbox will reenable the prompt after copying java code into your kotlin file.

Comment: That is the one. Thank you!